# PDF-File Sanitizer

Tags: pdf, security, command-line, .net, privacy

Do you know a good PDF-file sanitizer?

Free would be nice but is not a must-have.

The sanitizer should either be a .NET-Core library or a program that can be executed in Windows CMD.

It should remove Actions and JS-Code without sacrificing usability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) to find and remove potentially insecure content:

For example:

1. Remove all scripts in PdfDocument.SharedScripts collection.
2. Check PdfDocument.GetWidgets() collection to detect form fields and annotations. You can remove or flatten them if necessary. Sample: https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/FlattenFormFields
3. Check and remove interactive actions in certain objects:

   - PdfDocument.OnOpenDocument property
   - PdfDocument.OutlineRoot and its child objects. Use PdfOutlineItem.Action property.
   - Actions in controls (PdfControl.On* properties)
   - Action area (widgets of PdfActionArea type)
4. Check and remove file attachments in PdfDocument.SharedAttachments collection and in file attachment annotations (widgets of PdfFileAttachmentAnnotation).